# Refresh Facebook-access-token

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-oauth

We have a website that offers FB-login (https://desirio.com).

The FB-login is used to login a user and read his friends-list to show which of his friends also uses this application.

Current flow is like this:

current implementation/flow is:

1. User clicks the Facebook-login button which opens a local login-page
2. Local login-page will generate a Facebook login url with the requried permissions then redirects the user to it
3. Facebook redirects the user to the local login-page with a `code` to get the access token
4. Local login-page uses the code to get a long-lived access token (with ~60 days lifetime)
5. We store the access token and use it to get a live friends-list of the user.

Now how can we refresh the access-token every time the user visits our page (without user-interaction), so the 60-days-lifetime doesn't come into play as long as the last visit is not longer than 60 days ago?

Comment: Simplest way: Embed the JS SDK, that will always see to it that you have a “fresh” access token when the user revisits your site.